# Animation keeps the original image at the end

Tags: ios, core-animation, uibezierpath

I want to create an animation of a circle disappearing and I did the following code (based on other codes which I found on internet).

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    private var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       self.commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        self.tintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        self.drawCircle()
        self.addCircleAnimation()
     }

     func drawCircle() {
         let size:CGFloat = CGFloat(100)
         self.circleLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
         self.circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
         self.circleLayer?.frame = self.bounds
         let radius = size / 2;
         let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(size / 2, size / 2), radius: radius, startAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI) / 4, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat(M_PI) - CGFloat(M_PI) / 4, clockwise: true)
         self.circleLayer?.path = path.CGPath
         self.circleLayer?.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
         self.circleLayer?.strokeColor = self.tintColor.CGColor
         self.circleLayer?.lineWidth = CGFloat(2.0)
         self.circleLayer?.rasterizationScale = 2.0 * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
         self.circleLayer?.shouldRasterize = true

         self.layer.addSublayer(self.circleLayer!)
      }



      func addCircleAnimation() {

           let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
           animation.fromValue = 0.0
           animation.toValue = 1.0

           animation.duration = CFTimeInterval(floatLiteral: 1)
           animation.removedOnCompletion = false
           animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
           animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

           animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
           animation.delegate = self
           self.circleLayer?.addAnimation(animation, forKey:"strokeStart")

      }
   }
```

However when the animation finishes it leaves the original circle, even if I detect with `animationDidStop` it still has an effect of flickering. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You can remove the circleLayer in animationDidStop and the circle will disappear after animating.You can try the code in answer below

Comment: I found the problem, rather than using `kCAFillModeBackwards` I had to use `kCAFillModeForwards`. However as I don't know the reason for that I'll mask the correct answer for the better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Code to remove circle layer:

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    private var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        self.tintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        self.drawCircle()
        self.addCircleAnimation()
    }
    override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool)
    {
        self.circleLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }

    func drawCircle() {
        let size:CGFloat = CGFloat(100)
        self.circleLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        self.circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        self.circleLayer?.frame = self.bounds
        let radius = size / 2;
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(size / 2, size / 2), radius: radius, startAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI) / 4, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat(M_PI) - CGFloat(M_PI) / 4, clockwise: true)
        self.circleLayer?.path = path.CGPath
        self.circleLayer?.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        self.circleLayer?.strokeColor = self.tintColor.CGColor
        self.circleLayer?.lineWidth = CGFloat(2.0)
        self.circleLayer?.rasterizationScale = 2.0 * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        self.circleLayer?.shouldRasterize = true

        self.layer.addSublayer(self.circleLayer!)
    }


    /** UPDATED. Add animation for strokEnd instead of strokeStart **/
    func addCircleAnimation() {

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.delegate = self
        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = 1.0

        animation.duration = CFTimeInterval(floatLiteral: 1)
        animation.removedOnCompletion = false
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

        animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        animation.delegate = self
        self.circleLayer?.addAnimation(animation, forKey:"strokeEnd")


    }
}
```

Comment: I know, as said it still gives me a flickering effect, meaning that it is drawn completely and then it is removed.

Comment: You try the animation in "strokeEnd" and check if it helps. Answer updated.

Comment: If I use Start -> End it keeps the flickering effect. If I use End -> Start or End -> End, the circle appears rather than disappearing.